# Set different background-colors for events in the jQuery weekcalendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am working with [jQuery weekcalendar plugin](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) to show a webbased calendar with appointments. The color of all events is set in this CSS part:

```
.wc-cal-event {
    background-color: #00BFFF;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I just implemented the feature that a new appointment in the calendar belongs to a category (like in Outlook). Based on this category, the background color of the appointment should change, let's say it should be red.

How can I change the background of an event dynamically? When I change `.wc-cal-event`, every background of each event is affected.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you could create a fiddle showing this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in this function:

```
eventRender : function(calEvent, $event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, appointment) {
                $event.css('backgroundColor', appointment.htmlColor);
                $event.css('color', appointment.textColor);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each event it's own class e.g. `.wc-cal-event.meeting` and apply your styling to that.